# InvalidKeySpecException when reading RSA private while building Spring bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, cryptography, rsa, javabeans

I am working with a legacy code base and encountering really puzzling behavior while instantiating RSAPrivateKey.

I have a RSA private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Based on the headers it looks like the RSA private key is in format PKCS#1.

I then have Spring config class as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
    // Gets the above RSA key from config file
    @Value("${key}")
    private String key;

    @Bean
    public String someRandomTestBean() {
        try {
            // builds the RSAPrivateKey without any errors even though key is in PKCS#1 format. Why???
            RSAPrivateKey testKey = getRSAPrivateKeyFromPem(key);
        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            log.error("failed to read RSA key");
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeObject anotherBean() {
        SomeObjectBuilder builder = new SomeObjectBuilder();

        RSAPrivateKey testKey = null;
        try {

            // This fails to build the key with exception: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : algid parse error, not a sequence
            // Okay that is expected since key is in PKCS#1 format
            // What's odd here is that key is built successfully while constructing
            // someRandomTestBean bean. How is that possible???
            RSAPrivateKey testKey = getRSAPrivateKeyFromPem(key);

            // Gets weirder here
            // There is duplicate code in this legacy code base so TestUtil.getRSAPrivateKeyFromPem(...) is
            // duplicate of the private function getRSAPrivateKeyFromPem from below.
            // This also builds the RSAPrivateKey. How???
            RSAPrivatekye testKey2 = TestUtil.getRSAPrivateKeyFromPem(key);

        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            log.error("failed to read RSA key");
        }

        return builder
            .withKey(...)
            .build();
    }
    
    private RSAPrivateKey getRSAPrivateKeyFromPem(String keyPem) {
        String pem = new String(keyPem.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        pem.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        pem.replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(pem));
        return (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
}
```

I was able to generate a new RSA key in PKCS#8 format everything works as expected. What's puzzling here is that I am able to instantiate  RSAPrivateKey in some situations but not others while using the existing key, which appears to be in PKCS#1 format. Tried to diagnose for several hours now, but I've made not insight into it.

Comment: Yes that is PKCS1 format, not PKCS8 format, so trying to read it as PKCS8 format fails. If you have OpenSSL do `openssl pkey <pkcs1file >pkcs8file`. If you're using `java.util.Base64` and actuallly have PEM (which _always_ includes linebreaks), you must also delete the linebreaks before decoding, or use `getMimeDecoder()` which accepts and ignores linebreaks.

Comment: Right, but why does it not fail in `someRandomTestBean()` or `RSAPrivatekye testKey2 = TestUtil.getRSAPrivateKeyFromPem(key);`

Comment: It probably does fail but it's hard to see because all you do is log the message "failed to read RSA key" in the logfile. It's clear you typed in your code for the question rather than copy & paste, so that's a bad thing that makes me doubt your claims. Anyway, once the first `getRSAPrivateKeyFromPem()` throws an exception control jumps to the exception handler and skips the `TestUtil` call.

Comment: Actually, I did not see "failed to read RSA key" in the log file. Not only that but I could make use of `testKey2` from `RSAPrivatekye testKey2 = TestUtil.getRSAPrivateKeyFromPem(key);` in the running app without an issue.

Never truly got to the bottom of it. I am suspecting there might be something happening in the monolithic app that I am failing to see. Never truly got to the bottom of why the beans were allowed to build even though the key format was obviously wrong.